# Switch to two half hots - not working - help!

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image: Existing Wiring][image: Switch]Here is a diagram of my current wiring.  I cannot get the half hots to work with the switch, pretty sure it's user/DIYer error.  I do not know how wired within the conduit, just what's sticking out in the boxes.

In this configuration, the lower (hot) outlets work just fine, the upper half hots have no power.  Light switch is a standard switch, not 3-way.

If it helps, at the switch, the black and red wire appear to be getting power (indicator lights up) whether the light switch is on or off. It is a new light switch.

Any suggestions?  Thank you[image]
[image]

Comment: Used to work and now it doesn't? Or never worked? I think another cable is missing somewhere.

Comment: When you remove the tab, it separates the top from the bottom outlets from being connected together.  This means both the black and red wires must be hot/live to have power to both the top and bottom.  Will need to test if red and black have power with a meter, using a tongue hurts too much.  If black is the only hot from the panel and switch gets power from black, then the tops should only work when switch is on.  This assumes left black outlet is power from panel, goes to switch, then red from switch to top outlets.

Comment: OP:   I'm unsure if the half hots ever worked.        Tab has been removed.  The black and red wire on the outlets are receiving power (hot?) regardless if the light switch is on or off.  Posted new pic - notice no power to half hot on plug in tester, although red wire is hot.

Comment: If both red and black are hot at the switch all the time, someone goofed up big time or the switch is busted.  Would check the panel and see if any single breakers are tripped or off.  Do not turn them on.

Comment: If red shows hot with NCVT but doesn't actually provide power to the receptacle, it may be induced voltage from the black.

Comment: Is the tab removed only on one side (between red/black) or on both sides?

Comment: OP - Tab is removed only one the one side between the black and red wires.  Does it need to be removed on both sides?

Comment: Don't remove the neutral side tabs.

Comment: Something is missing. At a minimum, any individual box should have blacks & whites equal count, and reds <= blacks & whites. Switch appears OK (one of each). Left box *could* be OK - 2 black & white, 1 red - but right box has 2 red and white but only one black - **missing a black wire**.  Going through various scenarios, it just doesn't all add up. But starting point is finding that black wire.

Comment: @Manassehkatz, many electricians will wirenut the neutrals together and pig tail since this is required in MWBC’s so there may be a different number.

Comment: @EdBeal I'm aware of that. But can't tell from the diagram. We really need full pictures of all the boxes.

Comment: Manassehkatz + fully agree I looked at it and the sketch has 2 reds on 1 and 2 blacks on the other receptacle we need to know where the true hot comes in if at the switch the neutral needs to be connected, if over at the double red , or double black is the feed we need to complete the print to know what is next.

Comment: OP - Thanks everyone for your input - really appreciate it - and I WON'T remove the tab on the negative side.   I'll post some photos of the boxes to see if that helps.   I'm beginning to think that it's just wired wrong from the start...

Comment: New right picture confirms it really has 2 black, 2 white, 2 red - that's a relief! Still don't know exactly what's going on though. One possibility is power in to the left black/white, then black/red/white chains to right, then black/red/white to the switch. Which *should* work, but figuring out why it isn't would need a little bit of methodical multimeter work.

Comment: OP - Thanks for looking at the new photos and sharing your thoughts.  I was hoping that someone out there would be able to look and say this is what's wrong.  Drat.  Perhaps I'll just put in new outlets, not remove the tab, and forget about having 'half hots'.  :-/